Interactive Data Visualization for the Web Chapter 5 question about converting strings to floats
I am following the book Interactive Data Visualization for the Web to teach myself how to use D3 (using version 5 of D3) and I am having trouble understating what I am doing wrong, this is on page 76.
There is a very simple .csv file (food.csv) that contains two columns, one titled 'Food' the other 'Deliciousness'. I am loading the file into D3 using the following code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Loading csv File</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            d3.csv("food.csv",function(data){
                console.log(data);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

Since the Deliciousness values are loaded as strings, the book defines a function that converts the strings to floats, the following is code for that:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Loading Data and Converting Data Type</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var rowConverter = function(d){
                return {
                    Food: d.Food,
                    Deliciousness: parseFloat(d.Deliciousness)
                };
            }

            d3.csv("food.csv", rowConverter, function(data){
                console.log(data);
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>

When I do this, the data type of the Deliciousness value is not changing. Am I missing something very simple?
I have looked at the documentation for parseFloat and that does not seem to be the issue. I am wondering if I am just misunderstand where the rowConverter function should be defined.
I do not have a lot of experience coding in html or JavaScript so that may be the issue.

d3 uses fetch so the correct syntax would be:
var rowConverter = function (d) {
  return {
    Food: d.Food,
    Deliciousness: parseFloat(d.Deliciousness),
  };
};

d3.csv('food.csv', rowConverter).then((d) => {
  console.log(d);
});


Thank you, that did fix my problem. I will definitely have to spend some time learning about fetch, the book I have doesn't even mention it.
